# Why reaching nested meta gives NaN when normalizing a json with pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

My input is a Python dictionnary (json-like) :

```
d = {
    "type": "type1",
    "details": {
        "name": "foo",
        "date": {
            "timestamp": "01/02/2023 21:42:44",
            "components": {
                "day": 2,
                "month": 1,
                "year": 2023,
                "time": "21:42:44"
            }
        }
    },
    "infos": {
        "records": [
            {
                "field1": "qux",
                "field2": "baz",
            }
        ],
        "class": "P"
    }
}
```

I'm using the code below :

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    d,
    record_path=["infos", "records"],
    meta=[
        "type",
        ["details", "date", "timestamp"],
        ["details", "date", "components", "year"],
        ["infos", "class"]
    ],
    errors="ignore"
)
```

Which gives me this output :

```
  field1 field2   type details.date.timestamp details.date.components.year infos.class
0    qux    baz  type1                    NaN                          NaN           P
```

But I'm expecting this one :

```
  field1 field2   type details.date.timestamp details.date.components.year infos.class
0    qux    baz  type1    01/02/2023 21:42:44                         2023           P
```

To be honest, I'm going crazy with the `meta` parameter! I ignore what I'm doing wrong..

Can you explain its logic, please ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put extra `[]` in `record_path=`:

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(
    d,
    record_path=[["infos", "records"]],  # <-- put [] here
    meta=[
        "type",
        ["details", "date", "timestamp"],
        ["details", "date", "components", "year"],
        ["infos", "class"],
    ],
    errors="ignore",
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  field1 field2   type details.date.timestamp details.date.components.year infos.class
0    qux    baz  type1    01/02/2023 21:42:44                         2023           P
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much, you saved me hours! I would be more than happy if you can explain the logic behind those brackets and also the relation between record_path and meta, have a nice day!